# Shifting the domain of an interpolated function

Tags: interpolation

If I interpolate a list

```
 f=ListInterpolation[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}]
```

the result is in the domain `{{1,7}}`, so something like `f[8]` will be out of scope.

How can I shift the domain, say from 1,7 to 8,15?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to shift the function:

```
f = ListInterpolation[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]
g[x_] := f[x - 7];
```

Now g is a shifted version of f having the domain starting at 8.

Comment: Or to get a periodic function: `g[x_] := Mod[x, 7] /. (0 -> 7)`

Comment: @BobHanlon If one is aiming for periodicity, there is the [`PeriodicInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicInterpolation.html) option

Comment: @LukasLang - if you try that option you will encounter the error `ListInterpolation::per : 
  In dimension 1 the data at the endpoints of the fundamental period are not equal.`